# Expandable ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code to display a ListView using Xamarin Forms:

App.cs

```
public App ()
{
    MainPage = GetMainPage();
}

public static Page GetMainPage()
{
    return new NavigationPage(new DrilldownListViewByItem());
}
```

DrilldownListViewByItem:

```
public class DrilldownListViewByItem : ContentPage
{
    public DrilldownListViewByItem()
    {
        Title = "Drilldown List Using ListView";
        var listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = new ListItem[] {
            new ListItem {Title = "First", Description="1st item"},
            new ListItem {Title = "Second", Description="2nd item"},
            new ListItem {Title = "Third", Description="3rd item"}
            };
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");

        listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            var item = args.Item as ListItem;
            //if (item == null) return;
            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(item));
            //listView.SelectedItem = null;
        };
        Content = listView;
    }
}
```

ListItem has these properties:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

What I want to do is to show subitems when I tab on one of the main items. These subitems should be hidden at the beggining, but they should be there, I don't want to load them every time I tab on an item. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the visibility of the items you want to appear and disappear based on the click event of the list item.

On iOS you may also have to change the cell height (using HeightRequest), because it is likely that it won't change on it's own. I am guessing that android will work just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to specify fixed height. How do i get the required height automatically?

Comment: Have you tried setting HasUnevenRows to true? Its a property on the ListView.  This may help, but it is likely that it will not automatically do this, and you will have to force it. At least the last time I tried that is what happened.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that. The ViewCell's size does not get refreshed on WinPhone and iPhone.

For WinPhone, when I rotate the device to landscape and then back again to Portrait, the ViewCell is refreshed.

For iPhone when the ViewCell is scrolled out of the screen and then brought back in, the ViewCell is refreshed.

Comment: Then from what I know, you will have to use HeightRequest to for the size to update correctly based on the new content.